# i can not set server side cookie in http post request in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am trying to set cookie on the server when i make a http post request in expressjs but the cookie is setting when i make http get request. I don't know what could be the cause. Below is my code:

```
app.post('/tou', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private');
  res.cookie('__pal', 'locked', { httpOnly: false, path: '/', secure: false, expire: 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000 })
  res.send('done')
})
```

Comment: Are you sure it is **setting** when you are making a GET request, or is it being set when you make a POST request and then being sent back from the browser **to** the server in a later GET request?

Comment: It is setting when i make GET request

Comment: If it is, then that code is not the reason.

Comment: I used your exact same code and it worked on the POST request! This is how I fired the request from the clientside; ```var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", '/tou', true); xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        console.log('succssss')
    }
}
xhr.send("foo");```Got response: ```Set-Cookie: __pal=locked; Path=/```

Comment: Please how are you setting the cookie from the server in expressjs

Comment: I am using axios to fire the request from clientside

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue with this. From what I've figured out is that you cannot create a cookie on a `POST` request but when you do a `GET` request the cookie will be created. You should try this using a simple `GET` method on the browser and check if the cookie is created. If so **I think** you might need to figure out some way to do a get request once your `POST` request is done.

```
  app.get('/setuser', (req, res)=>{ 
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('name', "value", {
      httpOnly: false
    }));
  res.send('user data added to cookie'); 
  });
```

I would like to also add that if you test this using Postman/REST Client/Curl you will see the cookie but it won't be set so I'd recommend testing this on the browser.

(if you figure anything out please let me know)

**EDIT #1**

I figured out that you can use `res.redirect` to call a `GET` route then set your cookie that way.

Comment: The cookie was not setting because i didn't add credentials: true to cors middleware setting options

Answer (score -1):

Try using `'cookie'` module (`npm i cookie`).

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('__pal', 'locked', {
  httpOnly: false,
  sameSite: true,
  path: "/",
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 6 * 1000
}))
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference?